# Why do flexbox item images resize differently according to their initial size?

Tags: css, image, flexbox

I have four images: two small, two big (dimensions shown in html). They all have their img width set to 100% but their parent div is set to a specific width. When I resize the browser window the smaller images shrink and the larger ones don't, right away.

I have a red border around the divs and green border around the imgs. The smaller images' green borders shrink before the larger ones. Why is that?

http://jsfiddle.net/brcrnj80/6/

```
img {
  border: 3px solid green;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 250px;
  min-width: 60px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: i need a clarification.  Do you mean why do they exceed the boundary of the flex container? or why do they shrink to the minimum at different rates?  Because looking at your fiddle (in Chrome) they all size at the same time, even when I run the fiddle and the largest image is still filling in, they all resize at the same time.  The smaller images do seem to get to min-width first, but that just may be a perception issue on my side as the images approach the min value.

Comment: Worth pointing out that there's a webkit bug (all safari versions where flexbox is supported, mobile included) that prevents a flex container from wrapping flex items when they encounter a flex item's min-width (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136041). It's a pretty nasty bug and makes trying to use flexbox with `min-width` flex items virtually useless (due to the ubiquitous nature of safari on mobile devices).

Comment: @fnostro (In FF at least) The flower does not begin to resize at all until the mushrooms are fairly small.  Is this not the case in chrome (no access to chrome at the moment)

Comment: ok - based on that i'd say it's a rendering issue of FF - as @Adam suggests you may want to make sure your css includes all the different flavors of flex definitions.  See [**A Guide to flexbox** over at CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) at the bottom see the section on **Prefixing FlexBox**

Comment: I don't have IE11 handy to test it, but I found mention online of IE11 having even bigger issues when using `max-width` on flex items.

Comment: @fnostro - unfortunately, the min-width bug is not related to including all the flavors of flex definitions (of which there are many), this is an outright rendering bug (that hasn't even been acknowledge to my knowledge?) in Safari.

Comment: @Adam: I agree.  But perhaps I should have made this more clear.  When you have a case where a particular browser has a less than desired behavior, the best you can do is provide fallback for as many browser "kits" as possible.  After that, if there are no other programmatic solutions, you live with the results or you change browsers.

Comment: @fnostro - the work around is to just use a media query around the size that the flex items would have hit their `min-width` and change the layout rules (usually either by re-defining the CSS flex or width property of the flex item.

Comment: @Adam: ok, but that doesn't address the underlying issue of the OP which is improper rendering from different browsers with the same screen dimensions.  Using media queries to remove functionality to fix a rendering bug is not really much of a solution and it's not what media queries were intended to address.  But hey, if it works... I'm all for it.

Comment: @fnostro I wasn't trying to address the underlying issue (at least in the comments, but I've provided an answer that works below). All I was saying is that you shouldn't use `min-width` on flex items in the current state of affairs because of the poor support that all versions of safari have for this circumstance.

Comment: The Firefox vs. Chrome issue discussed above (e.g. in 3rd/4th comment here btwn James & fnostro) is actually a Chrome bug -- they're incorrectly letting `max-width` influence the resolved value of `flex-basis:auto`. (They're applying `max-width` too early in the flex layout algorithm, basically.)  I'm planning on filing a more detailed bug later tonight, and I'll post the bug number here for reference.

Comment: Actually, I realized that the Firefox vs. Chrome issue is a case of something being underspecified (with the spec changing from pretty-specifically calling for the Firefox behavior, to being less specific, over time).  So, instead of filing a Chrome/Blink bug, I asked the CSS working group to clarify: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Feb/0377.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

tl;dr: The items are resizing differently because they have a different `flex-basis`, which is based on the image size and is the value that they start flexing (shrinking) from. Every item has to shrink, but the larger items shrink from a larger starting-point, so they're still larger after the shrinking.  (There's also a late-in-the-algorithm "clamp" to prevent them from being bigger than their `max-width`; this is what keeps the large items from being crazy-huge in this case. But importantly, they *start their shrinking* from their `flex-basis`, and the `max-width` clamp is an afterthought.)

**FIX:** If you give each flex item the same flex-basis, e.g. `flex-basis:250px` (the same as their `max-width`), you'll probably get the result you're looking for. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brcrnj80/10/

(As noted in another answer, `flex: 1 1 0` (which can be expressed more concisely as `flex:1`) will also work -- that's setting the `flex-basis` to 0, and allowing the flex items to *grow* (instead of forcing them to *shrink*) from there, up to their max-width. Produces the same results, just via a different route.)

**LONGER EXPLANATION:** Here's what happens:

1. By default, everything has `flex-basis:auto`, which in this case means that each flex item starts out its flexing at its image's intrinsic width.  So your huge-image flex items have a huge flex basis, and your small-image flex items have a small flex basis.
2. We see if the sum of the flex items' `flex-basis` values are larger than the container. They are (because some of your images are huge). So, we have to shrink things.
3. We shrink each flex item "fairly", *starting from its `flex-basis`*, by whatever portion is necessary to make all of the items fit. So e.g. *each* item loses 1/4 of its width, for example (if that happens to be the right fraction to make them all exactly fit the container).
4. NOW, we check if any of these "tentative" item sizes violate the item's `max-width`. Your flex items with large images *will likely* violate their `max-width` at this state, because e.g. even if we take away 1/4 of their size (in my example), they're still much larger than their `max-width:250px`.  For any such violations, we *freeze the item* at its max-width, and we restart the shrinking process. (We do something similar for `min-width` violations.)
5. In the restarted shrinking process, the large images are frozen at 250px-width, and the smaller images are responsible for all of the shrinking.

So if there's not enough space for everyone to have 250px of width, your small flex items end up having to do all of the shrinking. (Unless we're constrained enough that the large items would be shrunk to be less than 250px *in the first round of shrinking* -- e.g. if we're shrinking each item by 90%, say. Though, then the small items will also be shrunk by 90%, and they'll be less than their `min-width:60px`, and they'll get frozen at that size and we'll restart the shrinking in the same way that I described above).

See [the "Resolving Flexible Lengths" chunk of the spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox-1/#resolve-flexible-lengths) for more details if you're curious.

Comment: Although they may appear to have the same effect in the current circumstance, `flex: 1` is the same as `flex: 1 1 auto`, not `flex: 1 1 0`

Comment: Nope, "flex:1" is indeed equivalent to "flex: 1 1 0". While the initial value of flex-basis is indeed "auto", the flex shorthand sets it to 0 (technically "0%" in the spec) if you provide a "flex" shorthand value without an explicit flex-basis. Spec references: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-flex-basis and http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox-1/#flex-initial  Specifically "When omitted from the flex shorthand, its [flex-basis's] specified value is 0%.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rendering difference between chrome and Firefox, but it's easily fixed by this:

```
.item { flex: 1 1 0; }
```

This tells the browser that all flex items should start out with 0 width, and all grow at the same rate to fill the remaining space.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at your JSFiddle, the issue is simply that the image box sizing doesn't include the border because it needs to be explicitly stated like this :

```
img { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

The img tags aren't affected by the flexbox which impacts only their parent div in your JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/brcrnj80/6/)
I think every CSS framework on the market includes this by default as a global definition, which makes us forget we need to set it up ourselves when needed.