# display:flex & image sizing/centering

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

I am using `display: flex;` to center an image and `max-width` / `max-height` to size it. There are several of these images - some wide, some tall, some square - and I want to be sure they are all a decent enough size to view them.

I assumed that if, for example, the image hits the maximum width and not the height, it should stay in proportion to the width.

Here is the issue I'm having. In chrome, it looks perfect for all images. In Firefox and Edge, they are skewed out of proportion.

[image: Compaison between chrome and firefox/edge]

```css
.image_block {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 140px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
}
.image_block img {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 170px;
  max-height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_block">
  <img src="http://www.paulruocco.com/jobjacket/assets/uploads/company_uploads/image_070816132332577fe19495484.png" />
</div>
```

I don't care which result I end up with (I can work with either) but I would like all three of them consistent. What can I do to accomplish this?

Comment: If you don't provide enough code to reproduce the problem, we can't review browser behavior and, therefore, can't help you effectively. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It's really just an image inside of a div. I edited my question to include a code snippet so you can run it on Chrome and Firefox / Edge to see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `flexbox` do not scale down images (that have an intrinsic aspect ratio) correctly in browsers at the moment, at least!
(For more info, you can look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568779/why-do-flexbox-item-images-resize-differently-according-to-their-initial-size))

So I have two solutions for this:

1. Set `flex-basis` for the `img`

```css
.image_block {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 140px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
}
.image_block img {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 170px;
  max-height: 90px;
  flex-basis: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_block">
  <img src="http://www.paulruocco.com/jobjacket/assets/uploads/company_uploads/image_070816132332577fe19495484.png" />
</div>
```

2. Wrap the `img` with a `div` tag.

```css
.image_block {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 140px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
}
.image_block div {
  margin: auto;
}
.image_block div img {
  max-width: 170px;
  max-height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_block">
  <div><img src="http://www.paulruocco.com/jobjacket/assets/uploads/company_uploads/image_070816132332577fe19495484.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Also I would suggest you use `flexbox` techniques instead of using `margin: auto`:

```css
.image_block {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 140px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.image_block img {
  max-width: 170px;
  max-height: 90px;
  flex-basis: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_block">
  <img src="http://www.paulruocco.com/jobjacket/assets/uploads/company_uploads/image_070816132332577fe19495484.png" />
</div>
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: This is great, thank you! Number 2 worked best in my situation.