# Keeping image aspect ratio in flex box

Tags: css, flexbox, aspect-ratio

So I want to have text next to the image, and both centered. Flexbox seems like it could work well for this but the image keeps getting squished. Any ideas of how I can keep the image in its original aspect ratio?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: red 1px solid;
}
img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
p {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="inner">Lorem Pisum Doelem sipsum iflup getsup in da tubsusb
  </p>
  <img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/15351700_300x300" />
</div>
```

This is an example of what I'm trying to do. I think flex box will work for this, I'm just having a little trouble.

http://mojave-demo.squarespace.com/our-team-mojave/

Comment: Seems like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545915/css-limit-the-height-from-scroll-dynamically/39546076#39546076) will help you here... Also note that there [is some issue with scaling down images while using flexboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259196/displayflex-image-sizing-centering/39397683#39397683)

Comment: and always better to wrap the `img` in a div...

Answer (score 2):

You will need to put the image into another container so that its intrinsic dimensions will not be affected.

```css
.container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: red 1px solid;
}

.image {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

p {
  padding: 30px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="inner">Lorem Pisum Doelem sipsum iflup getsup in da tubsusb
  </p>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/15351700_300x300" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/y5k9zqby/

```
.container {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
border: red 1px solid;
}

img{
max-height: 300px;
width: 100%;
overflow:hidden;

}

p{
 padding: 30px;
}
```