# Row flex container nested in column flex container with explicit height is rendered differently in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This simple example is rendered differently in Chrome than in Firefox or Edge; in one case the `main` flex item shrinks to fit the flex container (set to viewport height), but in the other it doesn't. Is the rendering difference based on some bug, or is it something else?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
main {
  display: flex;
  background: #f60;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <!-- any element longer than the viewport -->
    <img src="https://i.redd.it/e7a2rxhf1yrx.jpg">
</main>
```

**Edit**: [a more clear example](https://codepen.io/slikts/pen/jrXozE).

Comment: I think the issue is the default flex direction seems to be different in chrome than it does to ff and ie - open up your ff browser to have full height for the picture and then squash it width ways and you will see you have the same issue as you do with chrome when squashing it height ways. If you specify the flex direction, you will see they all behave in the same way.  Is there any reason you need main to be flex?

Comment: The default flex direction is `row` in both browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an inconsistency across browsers regarding how they may interpret attributes of flex boxes within flex boxes, but I managed to get it to work consistently across browsers by setting the height of the inner box to 0 and then setting the flex box to grow 100% (or 1) within the outer flex box. Here's an example using your code.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
main {
  display: flex;
  background: #f60;
  height: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <!-- any element longer than the viewport -->
    <img src="https://i.redd.it/e7a2rxhf1yrx.jpg">
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems `flexbox` do not scale down `replaced elements` like  images (that have an intrinsic aspect ratio) correctly in browsers at the moment, at least! And I believe this is what happens here.

(I read something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568779/why-do-flexbox-item-images-resize-differently-according-to-their-initial-size) and met with an issue with image as a flex item [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259196/displayflex-image-sizing-centering/39397683#39397683))

**Solution**:
One solution is using `max-height: 100%` on the flex item or even you can use `flex-basis: 100%` if it should always fill the parent height:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
main {
  display: flex;
  background: #f60;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <!-- any element longer than the viewport -->
    <img src="https://i.redd.it/e7a2rxhf1yrx.jpg">
</main>
```

Comment: Setting a fixed height isn't a solution since it defeats the purpose of using flexbox. The behavior also isn't specific to replaced elements; I just used an image to make it being scaled more obvious.

Comment: Well, we are not setting a fixed height but `max-height` (`max-height` is still a fix for this behavior difference in FF & Chrome) - and you are right, I guess this is **certainly** not about replaced elements.

Comment: I think the difference in behavior is due to the subtle differences of the browser implementations when they calculate width / height in nested flexboxes - can be considered a *bug*. As a general rule, its good to constrain the dimension in the direction of the flex to get consistent results in nested flexboxes. See this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzRVzA where `flex: 1` along flex-axis makes the cross-axis behavior consistent...

Comment: The point is that `100%` is a fixed value that only seems to work because there's a single flex item.

The `flex: 1` change doesn't seem to have any effect; the example is still different between Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: without the `flex: 1`, the `section` was also extending out in Chrome

Comment: I tested in Chrome 53 and 56 and it doesn't extend.

Comment: I'm on Chrome 47 and it does!

Comment: That's a year old, long outdated version of Chrome.

Comment: Well, that's true.